# roslaunch problem

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I use rosrun to begin a package, it works fine, but when I change to roslaunch it (it is a very simple launch file with only one node, and the package does not need any parameters), the package fails, the error information is: "process has died [pid 13287, exit code 255]." Nothing valuable is shown in the log file. Appreciation for any suggestions!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27610/roslaunch-problem/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch will add extra ROS arguments to the invocation of your node.  You should check to make sure that your node is capable of taking in these arguments.  Both roscpp and rospy come with libraries to filter these extra arguments out.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on 2012-02-14**:
Thanks for your reply, but could you tell me which libs of roscpp I can use, or where could I get the related information?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-14**:
http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Starting